# 0A hex bug on writing to file?

Tags: python, hex

I have a little problem:
why does this code

```
somefile = open('foo.txt', 'w')
somefile.write('0B0B0B'.decode('hex'))
somefile.close()
```

write 0B0B0B in file, and this code

```
somefile = open('foo.txt', 'w')
somefile.write('0A0A0A'.decode('hex'))
somefile.close()
```

write 0D0A0D0A0D0A in file? Where does that '0D' come from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It comes from the `\n` -> `\r\n` transformation due to the fact that you're running on Windows. Open the file in binary mode (`'wb'`) if you want to avoid this.