# Python's sys.stdout.buffer.write() adds extra 0x0d on Linux

Tags: python, console, escaping, newline

Consider the following code:

```
docker run -it --rm python:3.7.1-alpine3.8 \
    python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write( b'\x0a' )" | hexdump
```

Which prints:

```
0000000 0d 0a                                          
0000002
```

Since `sys.stdout.buffer` is a binary stream and the platform is `Linux` (i.e., not `Windows`) (see [0A hex bug on writing to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154369/0a-hex-bug-on-writing-to-file)), I was expecting the output to be plain `0x0a`.

It seems to me that `\n` -> `\r\n` translation is in fact taking place. 
How do I disable it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Ubuntu (or Mac Osx for that matter)

Comment: Can't reproduce either… probably some docker stuff going on there.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is indeed a docker issue. See [issue 2789](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/2789).